# Show that if the set of formulas $\Sigma$ is finitely satisfiable then the same is true for $\Sigma ; \alpha$ or $\Sigma ; \neg \alpha$

Tags: logic

Does it suffice to state the law of excluded middle here?

Assume $\Sigma; \alpha$ is not finitely satisfiable. Then there must be some [finite] $\Sigma_0 \subseteq \Sigma$ such that $\Sigma_0 ; \alpha$ is not satisfiable. Let $f$ be a truth assignment which satisfies every finite subset of $\Sigma$ - since $\Sigma$ is finitely satisfiable such an $f$ must exist. If $f$ does not satisfy $\Sigma_0 ; \alpha$, then it must satisfy $\Sigma_0 ; \neg \alpha$, and similarly for the remaining case.

Is that correct? If not, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to show that $\Sigma,\alpha$ or $\Sigma,\neg\alpha$ is finitely satisfiable. Hint: Assume what would happen if neither of them was finitely satisfiable (you then use some ideas from your post). The full proof is in the end of this post.

I have some problems understanding your proof. It seems to me that you use that $\Sigma$ is satisfiable, instead of finitely satisfiable (secret use of compactness?). Of course, if you assume that $\Sigma$ satisfiable then adding one of $\alpha,\neg\alpha$ is trivial.

> Suppose both $\Sigma,\alpha$ and $\Sigma,\neg\alpha$ are not finitely satisfiable. Then there are two finite subsets $\Delta,\Delta'\subseteq \Sigma$ such that $\Delta,\alpha$ and $\Delta',\neg\alpha$ are not satisfiable. However now $\Delta\cup\Delta'$ are not satisfiable, since otherwise one of $\Delta,\alpha$ or $\Delta',\neg\alpha$ would be. Therefore $\Sigma$ is not finitely satisfiable. Q.E.D.

Comment: Humm, yeah, compactness was assumed in my proof - this exercise comes right after a section on the compactness theorem, that's why I made that leap.

Comment: @wet : your $f$ will always satisfy one of $\alpha$, $\neg\alpha$. This is the bivalent nature of classical logic (the law of excluded middle). So your assumptions about variables are redundant. The claim is really an obvious cosequence of compactness theorem. Usually it serves as a lemma to prove compactness.

Comment: OK. I have a hard time gauging what amount of detail to put into proofs. Here particularly, I added them because otherwise it looked much too simple. I edited the OP to a new proof, without assuming compactness. How does it look to you now?

Comment: @wet Again your proof is confusing to me. I have added a full proof in the article. In your proof you again use compactness when you say there is $f$ which satisfies every finite subset. Then if $f$ satisfies $\alpha$ then it satisfies $\sigma,\alpha$, if not then it satisfies $\Sigma,\neg\alpha$ and you are done.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how I used compactness. The question states already that every finite subset of $\Sigma$ is satisfiable, so such an $f$ must exist, I did not make the leap that finitely satisfiable implies satisfiable. Anyway, I just saw your proof, thanks.

Comment: @wet Being finitely satisfiable tells you only that for every finite subset there is an evualution (possibly different for every subset). Notice that saying $f$ satisfies every subset is precisely the same as satisfying the whole set.

Comment: Oh, now I see it. My bad.

Comment: @GurIsmael The leap from "Suppose both $\Sigma;\alpha$ and $\Sigma;\neg\alpha$ are not finitely satisfiable" to "Then there are two finite subsets $\Delta,\Delta'\subseteq\Sigma$ such that $\Delta;\alpha$ and $\Delta;\neg\alpha$ are not satisfiable" needs more justification in my opinion. After all, if $\alpha$ is a tautology, then any finite subset of $\Sigma;\alpha$ will be satisfiable as required.